# Instant run using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run

what does it mean having this message, "Instant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk" ?

Comment: It means *Instant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match the local build on disk*

Comment: I guess Instead of hot swapping the changes on screen , it built and installed complete app

Answer (score 0):

The message is shown when an instant run isn't enough to update your changes, so Android Studio needs to rebuild the app and then push it to the device.
Read here for more information https://developer.android.com/studio/run/#instant-run the table explains that in case of

- Change the app manifest
- Change resources referenced by the app manifest
- Change an Android system UI element, such as a widget or notification

a new build is required